# Solving a set of coupled ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I have a set of coupled ODEs:

\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= -A x^4 + B_1 y^4, \\
\dot{y} &=  A x^4 - (B_1 + B_2) y^4 + C z^4, \\
\dot{z} &=  B_2 y^4 - C z^4
\end{align}

Without having to use the first one, I've managed to decouple them to get an expression involving only z and x: I rearranged the third equation to get another expression for $\dot{y}$. Subbing this into the middle equation gives

$$
\dot{y} = \frac{1}{4} \left[ \frac{\dot{z} + Cz^4}{B_2} \right]^{-\frac{3}{4}} 
\left[  \frac{\ddot{z} + 4Cz^3\dot{z}}{B_2}  \right]
=
Ax^4 - \frac{B_1 + B_2}{B_2} ( \dot{z} + Cz^4 ) + Cz^4
$$

However this is a horrible looking nonlinear ODE that I have no idea how to tackle.

Is there a better approach that I'm missing, or will I have to resort to numerical approaches?

Tagged physics since this is a model of heat transfer by radiation between three objects (x,y,z are temperatures).

Comment: Maybe it will help that $x+y+z = {\rm const}$ for this system?

Comment: Hmm possible. That’s conservation of energy by the way

Comment: Also after that you can go from $\dot{x} = \dots, \; \dot{y} = \dots$ to $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(\frac{y}{x})$ and this in theory can be solved by usual methods (this is homogeneous equation).

Comment: I like that approach but I'm not sure it's homogeneous unfortunately. That gives (I've eliminated y instead of z, since I'm actually interested in z): $\frac{dx}{dz} = \frac{-Ax^4 + B_1(S - x - z)^4}{B_2(S-x-z)^4 - Cz^4}$, defining $S = x + y + z$

Comment: But according to my understanding, that's not homogeneous because the quotient is not insensitive to a multiplication of $x$ and $z$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot about that $S$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help with this, I've learnt a bit about ODEs reading around for this one! But as a lowly phycisist, I think I'm going to just go with the numerical solution which serves my purposes fine.

Comment: By the way, if your goal is not to obtain the exact analytical solution, but to understand the long-term behaviour, we probably can do better than numerics :)

Comment: It's the frequency response of $z$ w.r.t. changes in $x$ (or better, another layer outside $x$, as shown in my answer) that I'm really looking for. However, this forms such a small part of my thesis that, sadly, I think it's time for me to force myself to move on from it and say "that's good enough"!

Comment: Seems legit! okay then :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, although I'd love to be proved wrong!

I've ended up just going for a numerical approach with this one. In case anyone is interested, this was a model for radiative heat transfer betwen three isolated objects with temperatures x, y and z. x and z only couple to y, whereas y couples to both the other.

As for a solution, I ended up adding a fourth layer which I held constant as a perfect heat-sink. Here's what happens if you step the perfect heat-sink's temperature. In the following plot x,y,z have become "chamber," "shield" and "cavity" respectivly.

[image: Step response]

And in the frequency domain:

[image: Transfer function]

So there you go. I'd still love to see an analytic solution if you fancy having a try!